# How to install GeoServer 2.23.2 Metadata extension

Tags: geoserver

I have some problem when install GeoServer 2.23.2 Metadata extension when I put jar file in lib folder and restart GeoServer, GeoServer crashes. I need solution for this. I use Java JDK 11 and GeoServer 2.23.2

Comment: How exactly are you installing it? What version did you download?

Comment: Geoserver version is 2.23.2 and Geoserver Metadata Extension version is 2.23.2

Comment: Ok, so how exactly did you install it? What does the log file show?